# The subject is not very clear

Tags: grammar

I would like to say "we plan to collaborate with more companies and teams to try our software collectively".

But it seems that the subject of "try" does not sound very clear (it should be the companies and teams who try the software).

Does anyone have a better way to rephrase the sentence?

Comment: As written, the subject of "try" could be understood as "we".

Comment: Yes, it's ambiguous. "Collaborate with more companies and teams" does not take an infinitive complement, so the subject of the final infinitive is up for grabs. That's just puffery anyway; why not just say _we will let other companies and teams try our software_ and avoid the self-congratulation?

Answer (score 2):

We plan to collaborate with more companies and teams so that they can try our software.

That's how I'd say it.

Comment: Is it ok to add "collectively" in the end? I want to say several employees in a team could try the software.

Comment: 'Collectively' suggests that the participants are sharing their experience with each other, which is unlikely unless you have a general open forum for discussion. 'Several employees' are a team, so it has already been said.

Answer (score 2):

Try using standard terminology in the domain.

> We plan to alpha test the software with groups of external and internal users.

This does some heavy lifting. Alpha testers are expected to give feedback and participate in the design. The phrase "companies and teams" is confusing. If teams means internal users, then "external and internal" users is common. The "collectively" part simply means you want groups of users.

Comment: "Test" is definitely better than "try" in this context. Unsure about the rest, "alpha test" has a specific meaning in many companies' internal processes, which may or may not work for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You might be trying to say, “We plan to collaborate with more companies and teams so that our software is tried in a variety of situations.”